# How to make GUI do the math while inputing variable in JTextField? and How to make a JTextField pop out when I click(select) a JCheckBox

Tags: java, jtextfield

new code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;


public class Gui extends JFrame {


static JTextField text;
static JTextField text2;
static JTextField text3;
static JCheckBox tsp;
static JCheckBox tbsp;
static JCheckBox cup;
static JCheckBox pint;
static JCheckBox quart;
static JCheckBox liter;
static JCheckBox gallon;
static JCheckBox oz;
static String unit;
static int conv;

        public Gui(){

            super("My title");
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

 final JTextField text0 = new JTextField("Enter the unit you are using at the moment (Tsp, Tbsp, Cup, Pint, Quart, Liter, Gallon, Ounce)");
            text0.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                text0.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(text0);
         unit = text0.getText();  ///////////////////////////UNIT\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


         final JTextField text = new JTextField("Enter the amount you have ( Must be a number.)",20);
            text.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                text.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(text);
        String str = text.getText();

        try     {
           conv = Integer.parseInt(str);  //////////////////////////////////AMOUNT TO CONVERT\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
        }

        text2=new JTextField("Which unit do you want to use:",20);
            text2.setEditable(false);
            add(text2);

//text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);
//          text3.setEditable(false);
//          add(text3);

            tsp = new JCheckBox("Tsp");
            tbsp = new JCheckBox("Tbsp");
            cup = new JCheckBox("Cup");
            pint = new JCheckBox("Pint");
            quart = new JCheckBox("Quart");
            liter = new JCheckBox("Liter");
            gallon = new JCheckBox("Gallon");
            oz = new JCheckBox("Ounce");
            add(tsp);
            add(tbsp);
            add(cup);
            add(pint);
            add(quart);
            add(liter);
            add(gallon);
            add(oz);

            HaandlerClass handler = new HaandlerClass();

            tsp.addItemListener(handler);
            tbsp.addItemListener(handler);
            cup.addItemListener(handler);
            pint.addItemListener(handler);
            quart.addItemListener(handler);
            liter.addItemListener(handler);
            gallon.addItemListener(handler);
            oz.addItemListener(handler);


            HaandlerClaass actionListener = new HaandlerClaass();

            tsp.addActionListener(actionListener);
            tbsp.addActionListener(actionListener);
            cup.addActionListener(actionListener);
            pint.addActionListener(actionListener);
            quart.addActionListener(actionListener);
            liter.addActionListener(actionListener);
            gallon.addActionListener(actionListener);
            oz.addActionListener(actionListener);
        }

private class HaandlerClaass implements ActionListener{
public JTextField text3;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

if(tsp.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(tbsp.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(cup.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(pint.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(quart.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(liter.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(gallon.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
if(oz.isSelected())
{text3.setVisible(true);}
}
        }




    private class HaandlerClass  implements ItemListener{
        public JTextField text3;

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){

            if((unit.compareTo("Tsp")==0) || unit.compareTo("tsp")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv/=3;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=.0208;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=.0104;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=.0052;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv*=.0049;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv*=.0469;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv/=6;

//prints converted unit
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);

            text3.setEditable(false);
            add(text3);
}
            if((unit.compareTo("Tbsp")==0) || unit.compareTo("tbsp")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=3;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=0.625;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=0.125;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=0.0156;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv*=0.147;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv*=0.0039;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv*=0.5;

//prints converted unit
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);

            text3.setEditable(false);
            add(text3);
}
            if((unit.compareTo("Cup")==0) || unit.compareTo("cup")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=48;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=16;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=0.5;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=0.25;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv*=0.12;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv/=16;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv*=8;

//prints converted unit
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);

            text3.setEditable(false);
            add(text3);
}
            else if((unit.compareTo("Pint")==0) || unit.compareTo("pint")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=78;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=32;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=2;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=0.5;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv*=0.47;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv/=8;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv*=16;

//prints converted unit
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);

            text3.setEditable(false);
            add(text3);
}
            else if((unit.compareTo("Quart")==0) || unit.compareTo("quart")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=192;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=64;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=4;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=2;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv*=.94;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv*=0.25;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv*=32;

//prints converted unit
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);

            text3.setEditable(false);
            add(text3);
}
            else if((unit.compareTo("Liter")==0) || unit.compareTo("liter")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=204;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=68;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=4.29;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=2.125;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=18/17;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv*=0.25;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv*=34;

//prints converted unit
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);

            text3.setEditable(false);
            text3.setVisible(true);
            add(text3);
}
            else if((unit.compareTo("Gallon")==0) || unit.compareTo("gallon")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=788;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=256;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv*=16;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv*=8;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv*=4;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv/=3;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv*=1;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                conv*=128;

//prints converted unittext3.setVisible(true);
            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);
            text3.setEditable(false);

            add(text3);
}
            else if((unit.compareTo("Oz")==0) || unit.compareTo("oz")==0){
                if(tsp.isSelected())
                conv*=6;
                else if(tbsp.isSelected())
                conv*=2;
                else if(cup.isSelected())
                conv/=8;
                else if(pint.isSelected())
                conv/=16;
                else if(quart.isSelected())
                conv/=32;
                else if(liter.isSelected())
                conv/=34;
                else if(gallon.isSelected())
                conv/=128;
                else if(oz.isSelected())
                {   conv*=1;

            text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);
            text3.setEditable(false);
            text3.setVisible(true);
            add(text3);
            }

}
        }
    }
}
```

Added actionlistener that use text3.setVisible(true)
text3.setVisible(true) is also used in itemStateChanged
still does not showup the JTextBox when JCheckBox is clicked
an error pops up in cmd when main is ran
and how do I "revalidate" JFrame?

Comment: what's the problem then??

Comment: JTextField wont show up when a checkbox is selected

Comment: Make a *minimal* example program that shows this behavior.

Comment: A recipe calculator where you inout a value on one JTextField, choose the conversion factor from the available JCheckBoxes and have a JTextField to popout whenever a JCheckBox is clicked/selected

Answer (score 1):

> How to make GUI do the math while inputing variable in JTextField?

*While inputting values.*

You need to add Listener on document of `JTextField` use `DocumentListener` for this.

You can do it like this

```
jtextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  calc();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  calc();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  calc();
  }
  public void calc() {
  //Do calculation
 }
 }
});
```

> How to make a JTextField pop out when I click(select) a JCheckBox

You can `jtextfield.setVisible(true)` on `actionperformed` of checkbox when checked and set false when unchecked.

Comment: what do you mean by "do calculations"
the calculations are being done already if a specific checkbox isSelected

Comment: @user3628903 I thought you want to get number from textfield and than convert it to int or double and want to do some calculation on that value and display to other textfield.You may use it for your purpose to just getText and use setText to store that value to other textField

Comment: so can a JTextField pop out while the program is running?

Comment: yes by the use of `textfield.setVisible(true/false)` method as well you need to repaint ans revalidate your frame.